# OCaml swapping elements in a list

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to swap two elements in a list, not really sure why mines not working.

The correct implementation should do the following:

```
list_swap_val [5;6;7;3] 75 => [7;6;5;3] 
list_swap_val [5;6;3] 7 5 => [7;6;3]
```

Here's two different implementations I've tried but both seem to just return the original list

```
let rec list_swap l u v =
    match l with
   |[] -> []
   |h::t -> if h = u then u::(list_swap t u v)
            else if h = v then v::(list_swap t u v)
            else h::(list_swap t u v) ;;
```

I also tried to do the above but with while in the match statements instead of using if, but both are not working. Where am I going wrong? Thanks for any help

Comment: What error message do you have? Please be more specific. Also, look at "a", "b", then look at "u" and "v" ;-)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I meant to keep the parameters the same. I'm just getting the same list returned and nothing is altered when I try to execute the code in the examples

Comment: When you see a `u`, the first element in your returned list should be `v` (and conversely for `v` and `u`). Here, it is as-if you build `h::(list_swap t u v)` in all cases. It has been a while since I coded in OCaml, but I think you can avoid using an if and use pattern matching to distinguish all cases.

Comment: Oh man you are exactly right, thank you so much that was silly of me, and yeah I will change it to using pattern matching to clear it up a bit thanks so much again!

Comment: No problem, it happens.

Comment: Just a side comment: OCaml pattern matches only match against constant values. They can't replace the `if`s here. @coredump this is a great answer, maybe you should transfer into the answer slot to get some karma.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I see, my bad, thanks. Based on your suggestion, I added an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to actually swap values: when you see a `u`, the first element of your returned list should be `v`. Here, it is as-if you build `h::(list_swap t u v)` in all cases.
By the way, you can factorize the recursive call, which gives you finally this definition:

```
let rec list_swap l u v =
  match l with
    | [] -> []
    | h::t -> (if h = u then v 
                else if h = v then u 
                  else h)::(list_swap t u v);;
```

Answer (score 4):

As coredump- wrote you can factorize it, but you can go even further and notice that this is a map.

```
let swap u v x = if x = u then v else if x = v then u else x
let list_swap u v = List.map (swap u v)
```

Answer (score 1):

as said above, you forgot to swap. You can also use List.map :

```
let swap u v n = match n with
     |x when x = u -> v
     |x when x = v -> u
     |_ -> n;;
let list_swap l u v = List.map (swap u v) l;;
```

This calls the function "swap u v" (thanks to partial evaluation) on every element in the list "l".

However, this hides the recursive call and you should know map isn't tail-recursive. If you want to use map and have tail recursivity :

```
let list_swap l u v = List.rev (List.rev_map swap (u v) l);;
```

"rev_map" is the same as "map" except it reverses the list at the same time, and it is tail recursive. So you reverse the list once again afterwards. "rev" is also tail recursive !